# What is the difference between 'chetana' and 'chaitanya'?

Tags: terminology, meaning, nirukta

We generally come across these two words in the scriptures. For example, you can see both in Lalitha sahastranaamas.

Although they look similar, the meanings of both are different. Afaik, Chaitanya exists where Chetana is absent. But not vice versa.

What is the exact difference between the two words?

Note: Please provide the actual scriptural meanings and hence explain the differences, if any.

Comment: simple chitanya supreme soul, chetana is jiva.. god exist even in jada where jiva is absent. but jiva cannot exists on its own

Comment: Yeah, @PrasannaR. I am also thinking the same.

Comment: please refer my question on sodasha kala upesane of lord from sat prashno upanishad in that i clearly mention cheatna mean jiva that 16 th kala purusha and its abhimani devata is vayu or prana or hanuman.